# Why do atomic_refs requires unconditional exclusive access?

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, stdatomic

The standard says:

> ISO/IEC 14882:2020 [atomics.ref.generic] p3
>
> While any atomic_ref instances exist that reference the *ptr object, all accesses to that object shall exclusively occur through those atomic_ref instances.

Which disallows some seemly harmless behaviors with the presence of a `std::atomic_ref` like:

- Non-atomic operations that are synchronized (possibly with the help of a mutex) with accesses through `std::atomic_ref`s.
- Non-atomic read-only operations, while all accesses through `std::atomic_ref`s are also read-only.

Is there a real world problem preventing these attempts to be well-defined?

Comment: This is [LWG3485](https://wg21.link/LWG3485). I think it's just hard to come up with wording for the standard to achieve this, especially since you need to consider how atomics are implemented on most architectures

Comment: @François Andrieux
There is no argument that the standard is currently providing no guaranties. The problem is why and whether we could lift some of those restrictions.